# Compress image Data URIs of jpeg/png format in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome-extension, image-compression, lzma

I am developing a chrome extension, where I take numerous screen shots of my current chrome tab from my extension using [chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab). From this I get the image Data URL's , which has to be sent to the server. Each image data url's captures a size of 64kb. On an average I'll send 100 images which equals nearly 6 MB on each push. This seems to be costly, so I tried a compression technique [LZMA-JS](https://github.com/nmrugg/LZMA-JS). But this doesn't compress my base64 encoded image dataUrl to my expected size.

My question here is,

1. Whether the conversion of this dataUrl will help me?
2. Or should I try some other compression technique? If yes, Suggest me.
3. Or Should I convert these image data Url to canvas and sent to the server? Will this reduce the data size to be tranferred?

Comment: I'm guessing you started from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329481/compressing-base64-data-uri-images Also read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770051/is-it-possible-to-further-compress-a-base64-png-string

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Yeah I started from where u pointed out. Since those answers doesn't satisfy me

Comment: There is no way to further compress them by a meaningful amount.